# as3 tween runtime bug

Tags: class, debugging, runtime, tween

Greetings fellow explores, = )

I've been at this for quite some time now and have sadly met my match. for the sake brevity ill be quick.  i have a document class that runs a timer and programatically loads a movieclip and a for loop that stacks them one on top of the other. then a dynamic tween move them from one end of the stage to the other. here is the issue.When i run the swf occasionally one or two tweens stop mid-way and i havent a clue as to why that is.

document file

```
package {


import flash.display.MovieClip
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.events.*;

import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*; 
import fl.transitions.easing.None;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

public class Game extends MovieClip {

    //varibles 
    public var brickStack1:Array = new Array(1);
    public var brickStack2:Array = new Array(1,1);
    public var brickStack3:Array = new Array(1,1,1);
    public var brickStack4:Array = new Array(1,1,1,1);
    public var brickStack5:Array = new Array(1,1,1,1,1);
    public var arrayOfBricks:Array = new Array(brickStack1,brickStack2,brickStack3,brickStack4,brickStack5);
    public var brickLoader:Timer = new Timer(2000,0);
    //public var arrayLength:int = 0;
    public var brickStack:int = 0;


    public function Game() {

        trace("game");
        //addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER , loop);
        brickLoader.addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER , loop);
        brickLoader.start();



    }


    function loop(e:TimerEvent):void {

        //declare a varible for the for loop with Math.random
        brickStack = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) ;
        trace(brickStack);
        var arrayLength:int = arrayOfBricks[brickStack].length;
        //arrayOfBricks[brickStack];


        for(var i:int = 0;i < arrayLength; i++){
            //if(arrayOfBricks[brickStack-1][i] == 1) {
                var obj:Brick = new Brick();
                obj.x = stage.stageWidth + obj.width;
                obj.y = (i*40);
                addChild(obj);
                var brickTween = new Tween( obj,"x", None.easeNone                , obj.x,obj.x - (stage.stageWidth + obj.width*2), 4, true);



        }

        if(obj.x < stage.stageWidth + obj.width*2){
                obj.parent.removeChild(obj);
             }


    }

}
```

}

Brick class

```
 package {


import flash.display. *;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;

public class Brick extends MovieClip {





    public function Brick(){



    }

    //function brickTimer(e:TimerEvent): void {

        //trace("brickTimer");



}
}
```

would have place this code in the Brick class but i do not know how reference Brick within its class's source code

would greatly appreciate any assistance .Thank you so very much

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as for your other question:

Tweens usually prematurly stops when they are garbage collected.

for example:

```
var tweenObject:Tween;
brickTween = new Tween( firstTweenParams ); // first tween added
brickTween = new Tween( secondTweenParams ); /* second tween added 
and first MARKED for garbage collection (removal)*/
```

When marked for garbage collection, tween will work some time untill collected (destroyed). it may occur before tween finishes his work

There are 2 solutions:

1) You should store array of all your working tweens to avoid your issue. And clean worked out elements from array afterwards.

2) use tween library like:

GTween http://gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/

or

tweenmax http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/